# Eclipselink Inheritance Problem: Relation to SuperClass query all SubClasses

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance, eclipselink, java-ee-6

I have a problem with Java Inheritance / JPA:

In my code, i have the following class-structure:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class A {
  .. some fields
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "V_B")
public class B extends A {
  .. some other fields
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "V_C")
public class C extends A {
  .. some other fields
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "V_X")
public class X {
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")
   private A data;
   ...
}
```

So Class X can refer to an object of type B or C.
If I load an object of type X, i see select-statements performed to class B and to class C with the value of A_ID.
If I have for example ten subclasses of A, there will always be ten select-statements to find the one linked object.

Is there any possibility to prevent this (and to reduce therefore performance)? I.e. by adding any further information to class X of which type the concrete linked A-object is?

Comment: Table per class is less efficient for this reason. If you are going to be adding information on the table, why not look into having a table for A that would include only the ID and a discriminator value?

Comment: You mean switch to "InheritanceType.JOINED" but have only ID + discriminator as common columns?